# Chemical reaction as a graphical object and chemmacros

Tags: graphics, numbering, environments, chemistry, chemmacros

I would like to include a picture of a reaction (png/pdf) inside `chemmacros`'s `reactions` environment (also alongside with other reaction schemes) in order to keep up with the rest of reactions' numbers. Assume the raster/vector image is necessary and I cannot use `chemfig` of `tikz` for drawing that.

When I run the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {graphics/} }

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
    2 H2O <=>[ $K_\mathrm{eq}$ ] H3O+ + OH-
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Diels-Alder_rxn}
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

I receive tons of error messages:

```
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: File `Diels\chemformula_single_bond: Alder\chemformula_subscript:n rxn' not found. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: File `Diels\chemformula_single_bond: Alder\chemformula_subscript:n rxn' not found. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
line 14: Extra \endcsname. \end
line 14: Overfull \hbox (4692.08719pt too wide) in paragraph
```

So what is the proper way of including a graphical object into `reaction`/`reactions` environment, and number it accordingly?

Here is a little example of what I expect to see upon compilation:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chemmacros` per default uses `chemformula` for the reactions. `chemformula` treats numbers (here `0.8`) as subscripts to compounds if they appear somewhere in between non-space tokens. But it provides users with an escape mechanism: `"..."`. Also, you're missing a `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {graphics/} }

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
    2 H2O <=>[ $K_\mathrm{eq}$ ] H3O+ + OH- \\
    "\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Diels-Alder_rxn}"
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason I get a [cluttered mix of both reactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koT1d.png) with a single {1} number. Is it me being stupid or it's how `chemformula` supposed to work?

Comment: Obviously the image is too big so it protrudes in the margin. The alignment is expected: the lower left corner of the image… IMHO what you want to achive is easier done with `chemfig`.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it -- isn't `width=0.8\linewidth` is what limits image size so it doesn't protrude? Also, `chemfig` is too complicated for me, I need a GUI-based app for image generation as I primarily draw clusters and assemblies with more that 50 atoms per compound. Using `chemfig` for that makes me insane.

Comment: @andselisk you're missing a ``\\``

Comment: Good point, my bad. But now [the reactions are aligned to the right and the {2} number is still too low on the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvM1n.png). I edited my question and I added an image of how I think it should look like.

Comment: @andselisk you may try `"\vcenter{\includegraphics[...]{...}}"`

Comment: Using `\vcenter{...}` causes a lot of errors such as `Missing $ inserted. ^^I\end` and `Extra }, or forgotten $. ^^I\end`.

Comment: @andselisk `"$\vcenter{\includegraphics[...]{...}}$"`

Comment: @andselisk maybe even `"$ \vcenter{\mbox{...}}$"` – I'm not sure right now

Comment: `$\vcenter{\hbox{...}}$` is actually better -- at least now the numbers are properly aligned, but still the [equations are aligned to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq5nx.png).

Comment: @andselisk that is because `reactions` behaves like `amsmath`'s `align`. It's probably easier just using two `reaction` environments…

Comment: Yaay, it seems like now it looks like intended. I uploaded the code here https://pastebin.com/4s6ciGM0, and now [the reactions look more or less acceptable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvCUk.png) if you add one image per `reaction` environment. If you have some time in the future, please feel free to review it and add to your answer. Thank you for your time and for developing and maintaining this and other packages!